# <FileMatch> added in Htaccess causes Internal Server Error 500

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I had font-loading problem.

So I added this code to my root `.htaccess`:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(eot|otf|woff|ttf)$">
  SetEnvIf Origin 
    "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(domain1\.org|domain\.com)$" origin_is=$0
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{origin_is}e env=origin_is
</FilesMatch>
```

But the server throws Error 500.

I also have enabled mod_headers, and have checked it with phpinfo() to see if it's loaded or not, and it says it's loaded.

I have restarted the WAMP, but still the problem exists.

Comment: Is that char `»` really contained literally in the configuration? That should not be.

Comment: Also note that you have a problem with your value substitution: `$0` will be resolved to `s` for https urls, if I am not totally mistaken...

Comment: What's your intent behind `SetEnvIf Origin`?

Comment: I have copied this code block from net, I want to allow inclusion of web-fonts

Comment: The `»` most likely is an artefact to make a line readable which would otherwise be "broken" by a linebreak in a print display. However it breaks the syntax, remove it and remove the linebreak there as well, taht should be a single line. BTW: you could see that yourself by simply taking a look at the documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif